# I am overriding a method in HTMLCalendar class. But it gives me an error. How do I inherit this correctly?

Tags: python

```
    class foo(HTMLCalendar):
        def formatday(self, day, weekday, data):
            if day==0
                return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>'

            else:
                return '<td class="%s">%d %s</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, data)

    a = foo()
    a.formatmonth(1, 2)
```

Whenever I try that it gives me an error saying formatday() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given). I am trying to overide the formatday method so that I can put some data in it. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are passing only 3 arguments in a.formatmonth(1, 2): self, 1 and 2. You need to pass another argument for data.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan formatmonth only takes two arguements. I am getting the error "formatday() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)".. The error is in formatday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that formatmonth calls formatday, and you're *not* overriding formatmonth, so formatmonth uses the regular arguments for formatday, ie, just day and weekday.

If you don't want the data there for formatmonth, then you could just give data a default value, eg:

```
class foo(HTMLCalendar):
    def formatday(self, day, weekday, data=''):
        if day==0: # note error here in original code
            return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>'
        else:
            return '<td class="%s">%d %s</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, data)

a = foo()
a.formatmonth(1, 2)
```

If you *do* want the data there, then your options depend on what that data is. Is it supposed to be the same for each day in the month being formatted? If so, then you could override formatmonth as well, or you could have the data be an instance variable, eg, take it from a `self.data` that could then be set with `a.data = ...`. If it changes for each day, you probably should have formatday get that data from somewhere else, rather than simply having it as an argument.

In general, overriding a method with a method that *requires* extra arguments, or has some incompatible API, is dangerous. Anything you don't override that calls that method will break.

Comment: @Constatntine Thanks for the reply! I see my problem. This is what I am trying to achieve. The data I will be putting in there will be the data coming fro database. So do I need to override formatmonth?